# After finding all the element matches a specified xpath, how to I get them using indexing?

Tags: xpath

When I do `/table/tr` (it contains all `tr` elements in a `table`), I can get the first one by using `/table/tr[1]`, get the second one using `/table/tr[2]`

how about when I do

```
//tr[contains(., "some text here")
```

(assume there are more than 1 `tr` contains text `"some text here"`

how do I retrieve the first one? second one .....

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should continue using indexing as you've described:

```
//tr[contains(., "some text here")][1]
```